# elements not getting appended to array inside the block

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I've created a script that basically gets the status codes on the url.
I'am trying to add the status code if it's greater then 399.

The elements are getting appended to array correctly outside the for loop block but not inside of it.
(here that array is TP)

```
ARR=('http://google.com' 'https://example.org/olol' 'https://example.org' 'https://steamcommunity.com')
TP=()
TP+=("77")
ERROR=true

#for item in "${ARR[@]}";do curl -I $item | grep HTTP | awk '{print $2}'; sleep 3; echo $item; done;

for item in "${ARR[@]}";
        do curl -I $item | grep HTTP | awk '{print $2}'| { read message;
                echo "hi $message";
                TP+=("57")
                if [ $message -gt 399 ]; then
                        #TP+=("57");
                        ERROR=false;
                        echo "$message is greater";
                fi
        };
                sleep 2;
                echo $item;
done;

echo "${TP[@]}"
```

please help, I am noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pipe results (eg, from the `curl` call) to another command (eg, `grep/awk/read`) you are spawning a subshell; any variables set within the subshell are 'lost' when the subshell exists.

One idea for fixing the current code:

```
for item in "${ARR[@]}";
do
    read -r message < <(curl -I "$item" | awk '/HTTP/ {print $2}')
    echo "hi $message";
    TP+=("57")

    if [ "$message" -gt 399 ]
    then
        #TP+=("57")
        ERROR=false
        echo "$message is greater"
    fi

    sleep 2
    echo "$item"
done
```

Where:

- while the `curl|awk` is invoked as a subshell the result is fed to the `read` in the current/parent shell, so the contents of the `message` variable are available within the scope of the current/parent shell
- added double quotes around a few variable references as good practice (eg, in case variable contains white space, in case variable is empty)